The data isn't saving in Excel even though the Excel file is created with a title heading
I created a program for fetching book details from Google Books API and generate its description using generative AI API. I also added the functionality to save the data in excel but its not working even though its creating an Excel just not saving data inside it. Its getting really frustrating; can you help me out please?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book Details</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Josefin+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..700;1,100..700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;  
            background-color: #FAF0E6;
        }
        .bookheading {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 45px;
        }
        .formISBN {
            font-size: 20px;
            display: flex;
            gap: 18px;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .formISBN input {
            outline: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            border: 2px solid green;
            padding: 5px 6px;
        }
        .button-33 {
            background-color: #c2fbd7;
            border-radius: 100px;
            box-shadow: rgba(44, 187, 99, .2) 0 -25px 18px -14px inset, rgba(44, 187, 99, .15) 0 1px 2px, rgba(44, 187, 99, .15) 0 2px 4px, rgba(44, 187, 99, .15) 0 4px 8px, rgba(44, 187, 99, .15) 0 8px 16px, rgba(44, 187, 99, .15) 0 16px 32px;
            color: green;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: CerebriSans-Regular, -apple-system, system-ui, Roboto, sans-serif;
            padding: 7px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: all 250ms;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 16px;
            user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            touch-action: manipulation;
        }
        .button-33:hover {
            box-shadow: rgba(44, 187, 99, .35) 0 -25px 18px -14px inset, rgba(44, 187, 99, .25) 0 1px 2px, rgba(44, 187, 99, .25) 0 2px 4px, rgba(44, 187, 99, .25) 0 4px 8px, rgba(44, 187, 99, .25) 0 8px 16px, rgba(44, 187, 99, .25) 0 16px 32px;
            transform: scale(1.05) rotate(-1deg);
        }
        .cols {
            padding: 0 25px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .col {
            border: 1px solid green;
            padding: 10px;
            max-width: 300px;
        }
        .col img {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .title, .author {
            font-weight: 700;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="bookheading">Book Details</h1>
    <form action="/fetch_details" method="POST" class="formISBN">
        <label for="isbn">Enter book ISBN:</label>
        <input type="text" id="isbn" name="isbn" required>
        <button type="submit" class="button-33">Fetch Details</button>
    </form>

    <form action="/save_to_excel" method="POST" class="saveToExcelForm">
        <input type="hidden" id="excelData" name="excelData" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="button-33">Save to Excel</button>
    </form>

    <div class="cols">
        <!-- Book details display here -->
        <div class="col">
            {% if title and authors %}
            <div id="bookDetails">
                <p><span class="title">Title:</span><input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="{{ title }}" required></p>
                <p><span class="author">Authors:</span>{{ authors }}</p>
                <p><span class="author">Publisher:</span>{{ publisher }}</p>
                <p><span class="author">Page Count:</span>{{ pageCount }}</p>
                <img src="{{ thumbnail }}" alt="Book Thumbnail">
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if book_details %}
            <div id="bookDetails">
                <h2>Additional Book Details</h2>
                <div>{{ book_details | safe }}</div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

            {% if error %}
            <div id="error">
                <p>{{ error }}</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            {% if description %}
            <div id="bookDescription">
                <h2>Book Description</h2>
                <p>{{ description }}</p>
            </div>
{% endif %}                     
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            {% if author_description %}
            <div id="authorDescription">
                <h2>Author Description</h2>
                <p>{{ author_description }}</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            {% if meta_description %}
            <div id="metaDescription">
                <h2>Meta Description</h2>
                <p>{{ meta_description }}</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cols">
        <div class="">
            {% if not title and not authors %}
            <form action="/fetch_details" method="POST" class="formISBN">
                <label for="book">Book Name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="book" name="book" required><br>
                <label for="author">Author:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="author" name="author" required><br><br>
                <button type="submit" class="button-33">Submit</button>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    
    <script>
        // JavaScript function to save data to input field when the page is loaded
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var excelDataInput = document.getElementById('excelData');
            var bookDetailsElements = document.querySelectorAll('#bookDetails p');
            var bookDetailsText = '';
            var excelDataInput = document.getElementById('excelData');

            // Iterate over each relevant element and concatenate their text content
            // Iterate over each relevant element and concatenate their text content
                bookDetailsElements.forEach(function(element) {
                    bookDetailsText += element.textContent + '\n';
                });

                // Set the concatenated text as the value of the hidden input field
                excelDataInput.value = bookDetailsText;
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>

Flask Code
FLASK CODE
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import google.generativeai as genai
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os

app = Flask(_name_)

# Configure Google API key for Google Books API
google_api_key = ''

# Configure GenAI API key
genai_api_key = ''
genai.configure(api_key=genai_api_key)
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')

def fetch_book_details(isbn, google_api_key):
    url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:{isbn}&key={google_api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    
    if 'items' in data:
        for item in data['items']:
            volume_info = item.get('volumeInfo')
            if volume_info:
                title = volume_info.get('title', 'No Title')
                authors = volume_info.get('authors', ['Unknown Author'])
                image_links = volume_info.get('imageLinks', {})
                thumbnail = image_links.get('thumbnail', 'No Image')
                publisher = volume_info.get('publisher', 'No Publisher Found')
                pageCount = volume_info.get('pageCount', 'Page count not available')
                return title, authors, thumbnail, publisher, pageCount
    # If book details are not found, return None
    return None, None, None, None, None

def get_response(prompt, generation_config={}):
    response = model.generate_content(contents=prompt, generation_config=generation_config)
    return response

def save_to_excel(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Title', 'Authors', 'Publisher', 'Page Count'])
    df.to_excel('book_details.xlsx', index=False)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/fetch_details', methods=['POST'])
def fetch_details():
    isbn = request.form.get('isbn')
    if isbn:
        # Fetch details using ISBN
        title, authors, thumbnail, publisher, pageCount = fetch_book_details(isbn, google_api_key)
        categories = "Your categories"  # Provide a default value or leave it empty
        ageGroup = "Your age group"      # Provide a default value or leave it empty
        if title and authors:
            book_description = get_response(f"Book Description Prompt: Craft a compelling description for the book '{title}' by {' and '.join(authors)}, in exact 300 words. Highlight the key themes, plot points, and unique selling proposition, emphasizing what makes this book truly exceptional and captivating potential readers with its intrigue, depth, and relevance.").text
            author_description = get_response(f"Write an engaging biography for the {' and '.join(authors)} of the book '{title}', providing insight into their background, writing style, and notable achievements within 200 words. Capture the essence of the author's expertise, passion, and contribution to the literary world, showcasing why readers should be excited to explore their work.").text
            meta_description = get_response(f"Create a compelling meta description for the book '{title}' by {' and '.join(authors)} in 150-160 characters. Summarize the essence of the book, enticing potential readers with its intrigue and relevance. Incorporate relevant keywords and a captivating call-to-action to encourage clicks and engagement.").text

            bookDet = get_response(f"Provide details for the book {title} by {' and '.join(authors)} ISBN {isbn} in the HTML format, specific details are categories and age-group in number. Provide me these details in the aligned format, keep the headings like category and age-group in bold and the value in normal, and should have line space between both the data. Give me the HTML code.").text

            book_details = bookDet.strip().replace('html\n', '').replace('\n', '')

            return render_template('index.html', title=title, authors=authors, thumbnail=thumbnail, publisher=publisher, pageCount=pageCount, description=book_description, author_description=author_description, meta_description=meta_description, book_details=book_details, categories=categories, ageGroup=ageGroup)
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', error="Book details not found.")
    else:
        author = request.form.get('author')
        book = request.form.get('book')
        if book and author:
            # Generate descriptions
            manual_book_description = get_response(f"Book Description Prompt: Craft a compelling description for the book '{book}' by {author}, in exact 300 words. Highlight the key themes, plot points, and unique selling proposition, emphasizing what makes this book truly exceptional and captivating potential readers with its intrigue, depth, and relevance.").text
            manual_author_description = get_response(f"Write an engaging biography for {author} of the book '{book}', providing insight into their background, writing style, and notable achievements within 200 words. Capture the essence of the author's expertise, passion, and contribution to the literary world, showcasing why readers should be excited to explore their work.").text
            manual_meta_description = get_response(f"Create a compelling meta description for the book '{book}' by {author} in 150-160 characters. Summarize the essence of the book, enticing potential readers with its intrigue and relevance. Incorporate relevant keywords and a captivating call-to-action to encourage clicks and engagement.").text

            manual_bookDet = get_response(f"Provide details for the book {book} by {author} in the HTML format, specific details are categories and age-group in number. Provide me these details in the aligned format, keep the headings like category and age-group in bold and the value in normal, and should have line space between both the data. Give me the HTML code.").text

            book_details = manual_bookDet.strip().replace('html\n', '').replace('\n', '')

            return render_template('index.html', title=book, authors=author, description=manual_book_description, author_description=manual_author_description, meta_description=manual_meta_description, book_details=book_details)
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', error="Author and book name must be provided.")

@app.route('/save_to_excel', methods=['POST'])
def save_to_excel():
    # Retrieve data from the form
    title = request.form.get('title')
    # Create a DataFrame with the collected data
    data = {
        'Title': [title]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Specify the path to the "Downloads" directory
    downloads_dir = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads")  # Get the user's "Downloads" directory

    # Specify the full path to the Excel file in the "Downloads" directory
    excel_file_path = os.path.join(downloads_dir, 'book_details.xlsx')

    # Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
    try:
        df.to_excel(excel_file_path, index=False)
        return render_template('index.html', success_message="Data saved to Excel successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('index.html', error_message=f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

if _name_ == '_main_':
    app.run(debug=True)


As per github copilot, below is the issue:
The bug in your code is related to the incorrect usage of the special variable name. In your code, you have used name and main instead of name and main.
    app = Flask(__name__)
# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

The name variable is used to determine if the script is being run directly or being imported. When the script is run directly, name is set to 'main'. So, if name == 'main': ensures that the app.run(debug=True) is only executed when the script is run directly, and not when it is imported as a module.

So then what change should i made can you please help me out?
